# Xcode 8 debugging on ios 10 device not working

Tags: debugging, ios10, xcode8

I'm running Xcode 8 and trying run a debug build of my app on my phone.  My phone has ios 10.   When I run it, it hangs up on the Default screen.  This works fine when I run on an ios 9.3 device. The app is installed properly because if I stop debugging and run it directly from the phone, it's okay.  Anyone have this issue and find a fix?

Answer (score 0):

this also happened to me, make sure you selected all output.

[image]

Comment: The problem is that the app never runs at all.  It gets stuck at the the splash screen.